# "No header is present" error while header is present

Tags: xmlhttprequest, cors

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.example.com/contact. No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'https://m.example.com' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

Why do I get the error above, when the requested resource has the header below?

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://m.example.com
```

Comment: Please don't vote for closing this question, because of "a simple typographical error". It is not a typo, it is lack of knowledge. I didn't know that Apache doesn't set the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header when it redirects.

Answer (score 1):

I had this error, because Apache didn't set the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header when it was redirecting.

It works perfectly since I use

`https://www.example.com/contact/` instead of

`https://www.example.com/contact`.

Another possible solution is to use

`Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "https://m.example.com"` instead of

`Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "https://m.example.com"`.